# Prism5 + Unity, set view from another module for PopupWindowAction

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

I have ShellModule and AModule.
In ShellModule on Shell view i writed

```
<interactivity:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject={Binding ExitRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
    <interactivity:PopupWindowAction>
        <interactivity:PopUpWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <ContentControl interactivity:RegionManager.RegionName="ExitDialogRegion"/>
        </interactivity:PopUpWindowAction.WindowContent>
    </interactivity:PopupWindowAction>
</interactivity:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

But in Initialize() of AModule in RegionManager the "ExitDialogRegion" does not exist, so i cant add view to region.

Question:
How i can use view\viewModel from another Module in PopupWindowAction on Shell view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region doesn't exist because the ContentControl is not part of the visual tree, so the attached property won't register the region with the region manager.  You could try to create the region and assign it in code-behind, but I would actually recommend using a dialog service if you need a more dynamic behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by "dialog service"?

Comment: You create a service, maybe called IDialogService, that is responsible for showing your dialogs and dynamically showing the proper view based on the navigation path provided to your service.

I cover this briefly in my PluralSight course:  https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/prism-showing-multiple-shells/table-of-contents